# illegalStateException in onLoadFinishe

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fragment, android-loadermanager

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action inside of
> onLoadFinished
> at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1886)
> at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1905)
> at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:688)
> at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:646)
> at android.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:312)
> at android.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:278)

Why I am getting this crash in play store console for some of my users. This is not device or OS specific.

I am not doing any UI related transaction in onLoadFinished. I am executing ABCAsyncTask, and in onPostExecute of it, i am calling pausehandler to execute the UI.

Additionally, As I am using two cursors, so onLoadFinished in called twice here.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "cursor is null");
        return;
    }


    (new ABCAsyncTask(this, cursorLoader, cursor)).execute();
}
```

ABCAsyncTask ->

```
 onPostExecute() {
    LoadItemPauseHandlerObject loadItemPauseHandlerObject = new LoadItemPauseHandlerObject ();
    Message responseMessage = new Message();
    responseMessage.what = 1; // some int
    responseMessage.obj = loadItemPauseHandlerObject;
    pauseHandler.sendMessage(responseMessage);
    }
```

In android OS [source](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java) code:

```
void callOnLoadFinished(Loader<Object> loader, Object data) {
if (mCallbacks != null) {
String lastBecause = null;
if (mHost != null) {
lastBecause = mHost.mFragmentManager.mNoTransactionsBecause;
                    mHost.mFragmentManager.mNoTransactionsBecause = "onLoadFinished";
}
try {
if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "  onLoadFinished in " + loader + ": "
+ loader.dataToString(data));
                    mCallbacks.onLoadFinished(loader, data);
                } finally {
if (mHost != null) {
mHost.mFragmentManager.mNoTransactionsBecause = lastBecause;
}
}
mDeliveredData = true;
}
}
```

since finally {} block will always be executed synchronously after try {} block in the main thread, and in onLoadFinished() i am not doing any fragment transaction directly, so, *mNoTransactionsBecause* should reset to *lastBecause* then why this crash is coming for some of my users?

I am using :

> android.app.LoaderManager android.app.Activity android.app.Fragment

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding check

```
isAdded()
```

in your `handleMessage()` method of your `handler` possibly it would be in your `Fragment`.
Let me know if you have further doubt

Comment: can you explain, what is the root cause of this exception?

Comment: Ya sure, basically you will receive the event of handleMessage even after the fragment is destroyed and that's the case you get IllegalStateException. So isAdded() will give you false if fragment is not there. And as a good practice you should avoid using handler as there is LiveData MVVM available in Android.

Comment: Btw did this isAdded() check help  you?

Comment: I am not able to repro this. It is happening to few of my users. I will update once i upload the apk.

Comment: Try reproducing this issue with pressing back immediately when you think you are sending your event through handler with and without this fix so you can be sure about the fix

Comment: In onLoadFinished, i have used:
        mainHandler.postDelayed(myrunnable, 10); 
and also when closing the fragment, I am checking fragment.isAdded()
The above two solutions helped me to get rid of this crash faced by my users.